# How to display events received via post in a get route

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, handlebars.js

I simply need to display events I'm getting in a post route in my get route.

Route that I receive requests:

```
app.post('/events', (request, response) => {
console.log(request.body);
response.send(request.body);
```

Everything working perfectly, I can see the events in console and send the response.

But, I want to display this request in a view with handlebars.

```
app.get('/', (request, response) => {
res.render("admin/home");
```

How can I do that?

**EDIT:**

Thanks to Nagibaba, thats how it worked:

```
app.post('/events', (request, response) => {
console.log(request.body);
response.send(request.body);
global.data = request.body;
});

app.get('/' (request, res) => {
var rawData = global.data;
res.render("admin/home", {rawData: rawData});
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can save them in a database and display them in other routes.

Comment: I understand, but without using a database is not possible? I mean just displaying the last request in a view without storing it.

Comment: You can create a global variable and assign it there. Pls test it, must work